# Can't install Windows 8.1 due to driver error during Windows setup

Tags: windows-8.1, multi-boot, operating-systems, windows-installation

I just built my first PC, and I'm having trouble installing Windows. I wanted to install Windows 8.1, but I ended up installing Ubuntu because I could not manage to install Windows 8.1 due to an error:

> No signed device drivers were found. 
>   Make sure that the installation media contains the correct drivers,
>   and then click OK.

[image: Photograph of screen showing the above error message]

I don't know what that means and I don't know what to do.

So altogether this is what I need to know:

- How to fix that error to complete the installation of Windows 8.1
- How to uninstall or dual boot Ubuntu with Windows 8.1

Comment: Its looking for mass storage drivers for the sata drive controller, sometimes you can make a change in the bios to remedy this, something like legacy mode for Sata.